# JWT authentication token - why needs to be refreshed before the expiration date?

Tags: c#, jwt, webapi

I'm trying to build a webapi solution with JWT token authentication.

In WebApiConfig I'm adding the following lines to the register method to make the webapi uses only JWT:

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

Here's my OAuthOptions declaration from Startup.Auth.cs

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
     TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
     Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
     AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
     AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
     // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
     AllowInsecureHttp = true
};

// Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

As I understand - now I should be able to use my tokens for two weeks before they expire.
It's not the case though. When I'm working with my API, after an hour or so I again have to refresh it because my requests start to bet bounced with a 401:

```
{
  "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

Seems that it behaves a bit like a normal session which I'd like to avoid. Is there any way to make sure I can can get back with my token a week later and process requests?